# TypeError: expected 1D vector for x

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, linear-regression, polynomials

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: expected 1D vector for x

with regards to this line:

> coefficients = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 1)

```
coefficients = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
ys = polynomial(x1)
```

x1 & y1 are;

```
x = frame_query("select * from table",db)
y = frame_query("select * from table",db)

x1 = np.array(x)
y1 = np.array(y)
```

Consisting of 736 rows of data. I want to regress one row onto the other. Could someone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: I think we need more information about the dataframe. How do you create/get x1 and y1? Can you edit your question to provide this information?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. What is x1.shape? What module does frame_query come from?

Comment: What's the source of `x1`, `y1`?  The mention of a dataframe suggests `pandas`, but you don't have a `pandas` tag

Comment: Also FYI looking at the doc string for pandas.io.sql.frame_query (I assume this is what you're using?) it seems this function is depreciated, instead read_sql is preferred.

Comment: yes, i have `pandas.io.sql.frame_query`. It should be `pandas.io.sql.read_sql`?

Comment: I haven't used the `pandas.io.sql` module, so I'm not sure what the difference is. Give it a try, but you also might want to add this info to your question in case someone who knows more about interfacing pandas & sql can help.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` one dimensional? After you convert to `x1` and `y1`, what is the shape (`x1.shape` and `y1.shape`)?

Comment: I edited my answer below, so if the shape of x1 and y1 is the issue, then that's how you solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to turn the data frame into a 1D array. First let me create a data frame

```
import pandas
d = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['x1','y1'])
```

I think the following does what you want:

```
import numpy
x1 = numpy.array(d['x1'])
y1 = numpy.array(d['y1'])
numpy.polyfit(x1,y1,1)
```

I think the problem you are having is that the arrays you're creating have an additional dimension. For example, the arrays `a` and `b` below "look" just like `x1` and `y1`,

```
a = numpy.array([[1,3,5]])
b = numpy.array([[2,4,6]])
```

but because of the double bracket (`[[...]]`) they are actually two-dimensional. I can reduce the dimension by selecting just the 0th column:

```
x1 = a[0,:]
y1 = b[0,:]
```

Then the polyfit will work. EDIT: if you look at the shape of the arrays (e.g. `x1.shape`) you should be able to tell if you have "extra dimensions."

Answer (score 1):

Try to make x1 and y1 np.array:

```
x1 = np.array([45,34,12])
y1 = np.array([19,46,22])
```

Comment: i get  `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 736 to array axis with dimension 1`

Comment: Can you give more info about your x1 and y1? from your original post it seems that are 1D vectors of 3 elements each. Where you get size 736??? The polyfit it works for me when i use np.array